# Where are the test cases in Qt?

Tags: qt

I have gone through Qtestlib manual & tutorial and got to know step by step procedure for developing a test.

If i'm right, Qt has already developed few test cases for testing its functionalities. Can anyone tell me where are those codes in Qt's source tree?

If i have to modify them(test cases), is it possible for me to do?

Thanks in advance,
Niv

Answer (score 5):

The unit tests are not included in the source distributions, but they are present in the Git repository: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.7/tests/auto