# Online medical image processing grand challenges

Tags: image-processing, classification, image-recognition, medical

I'm currently working on my thesis, and I'm looking for an/some online medical image processing grand challenge(s). I already know [this site](http://www.grand-challenge.org/index.php/Main_Page) but I need a challenge which has microscopic image dataset like cells, chromosomes, bacterias, viruses etc with classification or recognation objective. Like karyotyping.

Maybe someone is working on this field or his university made a challenge what I'm looking for, and can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you undergrad or postgrad?

Comment: The  headless closing monster attacks again! Comment (at least) if you vote to close.

Comment: I voted to close and migrate to http://programmers.stackexchange.com which is probably more appropriate for this type of question.

Comment: @Greg The OP is trying to get a set of hard to find test cases for his software. It's like (for example) [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995287/where-are-the-test-cases-in-qt)

Answer (score 3):

Have you asked your thesis advisor?  Even if the final subject doesn't come from such a discussion, you will get valuable time with your advisor.

A good thesis is as much about interacting with your advisor as it is about the subject.

Comment: Yes, I have spoken with him. The thing is that we have a software library what we are using on other fields of the image processing, and we would like to expand it for this field too.

We got a promise from one company to get such image database but we haven't got it yet. We can make a dataset but the privacy laws of our country don't make the things easier. Of course we do it if there is not other way but it is better to find such an online challenge because then the resoults become comparable.